# Form disabled when offline using html5 app cache

Tags: android, html, application-cache

I have a website that is saved offline using the application cache.

When I access this website on Android using chrome all of my input elements are automatically disabled. This wasn't the case in the past.

Why is this happening and what can I do to get around it?

Comment: Having the same issue, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Sorry I didn't ever find any solution to this. I'm now using Vuejs to make a PWA with service workers. Much nicer technology to work with.