# How to prevent my form inputs on an offline site on android getting disabled by browser?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

I wrote a really simple, plain javascript + HTML web page, which main purpose is to interactively (using `oninput` event) calculate costs based on form inputs. It runs entirely on the client browser and works good on desktop browsers and locally as a downloaded site.

When I downloaded the site on android's Chrome though, the offline version of the site makes all form inputs disabled! The app would work just fine without any internet access, so I don't understand what's the deal with the app deciding for the developer, that inputs should be disabled.

[This guy had the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918147/chrome-disables-buttons-and-input-elements-when-offline), as well as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304550/form-disabled-when-offline-using-html5-app-cache), bot there was no solution posted...

How to make it work **with a relative low effort -- without some heavy frameworks, ground-up reworks etc.**?

Minimal reproducible example:

```html
<!-- test.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style> span {width:200px; display:inline-block;    }</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="F">
        <div><span>type="button"        </span><input type="button"           id="_button">                  <label for="_button">         </label></div>
        <div><span>type="checkbox"      </span><input type="checkbox"         id="_checkbox">                <label for="_checkbox">       </label></div>
        <div><span>type="color"         </span><input type="color"            id="_color">                   <label for="_color">          </label></div>
        <div><span>type="date"          </span><input type="date"             id="_date">                    <label for="_date">           </label></div>
        <div><span>type="datetime-local"</span><input type="datetime-local"   id="_datetime-local">          <label for="_datetime-local"> </label></div>
        <div><span>type="email"         </span><input type="email"            id="_email">                   <label for="_email">          </label></div>
        <div><span>type="file"          </span><input type="file"             id="_file">                    <label for="_file">           </label></div>
        <div><span>type="hidden"        </span><input type="hidden"           id="_hidden">                  <label for="_hidden">         </label></div>
        <div><span>type="image"         </span><input type="image"            id="_image">                   <label for="_image">          </label></div>
        <div><span>type="month"         </span><input type="month"            id="_month">                   <label for="_month">          </label></div>
        <div><span>type="number"        </span><input type="number"           id="_number">                  <label for="_number">         </label></div>
        <div><span>type="password"      </span><input type="password"         id="_password">                <label for="_password">       </label></div>
        <div><span>type="radio"         </span><input type="radio"            id="_radio">                   <label for="_radio">          </label></div>
        <div><span>type="range"         </span><input type="range"            id="_range">                   <label for="_range">          </label></div>
        <div><span>type="reset"         </span><input type="reset"            id="_reset">                   <label for="_reset">          </label></div>
        <div><span>type="search"        </span><input type="search"           id="_search">                  <label for="_search">         </label></div>
        <div><span>type="submit"        </span><input type="submit"           id="_submit">                  <label for="_submit">         </label></div>
        <div><span>type="tel"           </span><input type="tel"              id="_tel">                     <label for="_tel">            </label></div>
        <div><span>type="text"          </span><input type="text"             id="_text">                    <label for="_text">           </label></div>
        <div><span>type="time"          </span><input type="time"             id="_time">                    <label for="_time">           </label></div>
        <div><span>type="url"           </span><input type="url"              id="_url">                     <label for="_url">            </label></div>
        <div><span>type="week"          </span><input type="week"             id="_week">                    <label for="_week">           </label></div>
    </form>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// test.js
[...document.querySelectorAll("input")]
    .map(e => {
        e.addEventListener("input", (evt) => {
            let label = document.querySelector(`#${e.id} + label`);
            label.innerHTML = "val: " + evt.target.value;
        });
    });
```

And to reproduce:

1. put those files in one folder
2. start live server on main machine
3. connect android via USB
4. connect to the live server in local network (192.168.0.x)
5. download the site offline in android's chrome
6. turn off transfer and wifi on android and try to connect again to 192.168.0.x - offline site will be loaded
7. in chrome go to chrome://inspect/#devices, and debug the offline site on android (that is still connected via USB!)
8. you can reconnect to WIFI and load the page in another tab to compare offline and online mode

The only difference I see is in the developer tools in Elements > Accessibility > Computed Properties — the input of the offline site has computed property 'disabled' and no 'focusable' and 'focused' properties.

Comment: Have you tried different types of input?

Comment: @vanowm yup, I've tested every single type of input (I'm updating the code in question), and none of them work :(
I've also tested setting explicit `enabled` on inputs - nothing changes.

Comment: What about [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) ?

Comment: Still nothing. Also tried forcing 'onfocus' callback and using html5 manifest. nothing works :(

Comment: Seems like the only way is making a PWA :(